# Overriding accessibility sounds on an android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, accessibility

I'm trying to make my application more accessible for people who are visually impaired. As such I'm trying to override the default accessibility sounds that come with the keyboard when the accessibility option is turned on.

As to my question - Is it possible to change the accessibility sound of each key without writing up a new keyboard altogether? If not possible, is it at-least possible doing so with the a new keyboard altogether?

Comment: No, this is not supported by TalkBack.